# How to prevent copying of empty file through azure data factory?

Tags: azure-data-factory

I am a newbie to azure data factory and working on copy activity. I want to prevent the run of copy activity for files which are empty. can anyone help me out with this?

Also, what would happen if an empty file is encountered in the copy activity? will there be any errror?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Lookup activity that reads and returns the content of a configuration file or table.

[Lookup activity in Azure Data Factory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-lookup-activity)